# How to redirect Shortcuts or Stop Shortcuts accessing a certain web page

Tags: shortcut, redirect

I have a website which contains an information portal prior to a seperate login page, i would like to be able to stop users creating or accessing the login page via a shortcut they have created on their desktop and redirect them to the Information portal in the first instance.

Thus ensuring all user can only logging via the Information Screen and not bypass this page.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I can only think of ways to do that server side, you could store in a session variable whether the visitor has already visited the main page (information screen) if he has not, then you can redirect him from the login page to that information screen, then when he comes back to the login page he will have the variable set in the session and can use the login page.

How to best store the session variable depends on the webframework you are using.